# AWS: Reading all files in an Amazon S3 bucket with a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an Amazon S3bucket with a trigger to run a lambda function that has access to the bucket. I want to make a function (with Node.js) that reads all the files' content and sums up digits found in it.
I couldn't find with google how to read files from an Amazon S3 bucket with a lambda function in Node.js.

Can you explain to me - what libraries do I need? Which functions in those libraries can be useful to me? Thanks in advance :) Oren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"Which functions in those libraries can be useful to me?"***

To read Amazon S3 bucket objects from Node JS, you can use the AWS SDK for JavaScript. That is, you can write a Lambda function using the AWS SDK for JavaScript. Then use the Amazon S3 JS API. To learn how to use this AWS SDK for JavaScript, including how to write Amazon S3 logic, how to write Lambda functons using this API, and so on, please refer to this AWS Developer Guide.

[Developer Guide for SDK Version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)